# How can I check saved items to sugarORM database, without delay?

Tags: java, database, android-studio, sugarorm

I have the following code, and after save the BookItems into SugarORM database, I need to update my layout with these data.

First of all I trying to get the lenght of my data, to do so, I create bItem variable, and I find by author in my database.

The problem is that checking the logs, all BookItem is saved after I get it from database.

I don't know if I'm saving bad my data or what I'm doing bad.

```
// Getting data from Firebase database
private void askFirebaseBooks() {
    fReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d("Count:", " "+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            BookItem tempItem = new BookItem();
            TempItem.getDataSnapshot(postSnapshot);
            tempItem.save();
            bookContent.addItem(tempItem);
        }
        bookContent.save();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
Log.d("Sugar"," "+bookContent.getLength());
final List<BookItem> bItem = BookItem.find(BookItem.class, "author=?", "Harper");
Log.d("Sugar-size"," "+bItem.size());
};`
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why is your List<BookItem> bItem, final? And do you mean that your : Log.d("Sugar"+getLength) is zero? I don't really get the problem